# Проблема с localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Доброй ночи. Так уж получилось, что мне необходимо написать интернет-магазин, и я застрял на моменте написания логики для корзины, которая довольно проста, на первый взгляд: нажимаем на кнопку  под нужным товаром, его данные (data-name, data-price, etc) записываются в объект, который, в свою очередь, записывается в массив shoppingCart, и хранится в localStorage. Т.е. при добавлении различных товаров они просто в виде объектов записываются в массив. Если все производить с одной страницы - проблемы не возникает, но сайт, по задумке, является многостраничным, и вот как раз когда я нажимаю "Добавить товар" с другой страницы, то массив в localStorage переписывается, т.е. ранее добавленные данные с других страниц удаляются. Собственно, был бы рад услышать мысли по этому поводу. Спасибо.
Объект корзины и его методы:

```
var shoppingCart = {};
shoppingCart.cart = [];
shoppingCart.Item = function(name, price, count, category, image) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
  this.count = count;
  this.category = category;
  this.image = image;
};
shoppingCart.addItemToCart = function (name, price, count, category, image) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.cart.length; i++) {
    if (this.cart[i].name === name) {
      this.cart[i].count += count;
      this.saveCart();
      return;
    }
  }
  var item = new this.Item(name, price, count, category, image);
  this.cart.push(item);
  this.saveCart();
};
shoppingCart.saveCart = function () {
  window.localStorage.setItem('shoppingCart', JSON.stringify(this.cart));
};
shoppingCart.loadCart = function () {
  this.cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));
};
```

jQuery:

```
$(".article-to-basket").click(function() {
  let name = $(this).attr("data-name");
  let price = $(this).attr("data-price");
  let category = $(this).attr("data-category");
  let image = $(this).attr("data-image");

  shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name, price, 1, category, image);
});
```

Comment: почему бы перед записью не проверить в localStorage есть ли там уже данные из корзины? Если есть, то получить их и добавить к ним новые данные.

Comment: Идея хорошая, но как не пытаюсь реализовать - не получается. Так же когда добавляю все на одной странице - все хорошо, но с других страниц значения просто перезаписываются.

Comment: Заметил такой нюанс, что значения в localStorage перезаписываются исключительно из-за обновления страницы.

Comment: На одной странице добавил и сохранил, на другой получил, добавил и снова сохранил.

Comment: pepel_xD, так и сделал, добавил в корректное место shoppingCart.loadCart(), и теперь все отлично работает. Примите мою благодарность.